# It possible to replace file to buffer while pass input to an exe as shell command?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm using "system" API calls to run shell commands in my C program, now
there is case where I want to redirect the output generated by an executableto a buffer instead of a file (named `recv.mail`)

An example of how I write the output to the file:

```
cmd[] = "mda "/bin/sh -c 'cat > recv.mail'";
system (cmd);
```

Similarly I want to replace input taken from the file (send.mail) with input taken from a buffer.

An example of how I take input from a file:

```
cmd[] = "msmtp < cat send.mail";
system (cmd);
```

NOTE: The `send.mail` and `recv.mail` files have formatted data.

Are pipes a better replacement?
Can anyone suggest another alternative?

Comment: Your "take input from file" example reads from a file called `cat`; I don't think that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

1. `popen`/`pclose` may do what you want:

   ```
   FILE *f = popen("program to execute", "r");
   if (NULL != f)
   {
       char buffer[128];
       while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f)
       {
           printf("Read from program: '%s'\n", buffer);
       }
       pclose (f);
   }
   ```
2. `popen`/`pclose` again:

   ```
   FILE *f = popen("program to execute", "w");
   ...
   ```